# Handling transaction when updates using ActiveRecord and DAO take place together

Tags: yii

I know that when we adopt Active Record updates during a transaction, we should use

```
$trans = $model->dbConnection->beginTransaction();
```

And when we adopt DAO updates during a transaction, we should use

```
$trans = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
```

But how to begin a transaction when we do updates via both ActiveRecord and DAO within a transaction?

So far, I have been using

```
$trans = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
```

for the mixed up case.

Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: I would be you I won't mix both ActiveRecord and DAO within a transaction.

Comment: Is there any problem in mixing ActiveRecord and DAO? I have many cases when I have to make complex parallel updates to other tables when I work on one model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a models `dbConnection` is `Yii::app()->db`. Therefore you can use `Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();` and that should work both for active record and DAO.
It wont work if you have different connection in active record and DAO. But this is the normal behavior and has nothing to do with yii, because a transaction works always on the connection.

You can for e.g. use two DAOs with different connections, but you cannot use transactions for these both since they have different connections.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am using only a single connection.